# how to store large files (pdfs) into the browser file system

Tags: javascript, html, couchdb, local-storage, pouchdb

**Background:**

I have built an offline HTML5 application that stores some data into the local browser db using pouchdb.

Now the requirements have changed and I have to store large pdf documents(around 200 of them, each with 5mb - 8mb size) into the local browser so the user can view it offline when required.

**Issue:**
I don't think that it is a good idea to put these large documents received from server into my in browser database using pouchdb.

I would like to know if there is a way to put these documents into my device some how and then get a url reference pointing to the location within the local device ?.

Answer (score 3):

Include the PDFs in your offline manifest, so that they're cached with the rest of the application. Then you just use your normal URL to refer to it, and it's satisfied from the offline app cache.

---

Re your question below:

> When the application is loaded in the browser then i store the details of the associated pages into the browser via a manifest file. And when the user clicks on a 'SYNC' button then I communicate with the server and fetches all the pdfs associated with the user. If I have to persist these pdfs using the manifest then how can I do it ?.....the manifest is already stored

The way we do something similar is this: We have separate pages for the things that the user has taken offline (a day's worth of appointments, for instance), and a list page driven entirely by client-side data that lists those pages. Here's how it works:

When the user wants to take something they're looking at offline, they click a button which opens a URL with the information telling the server what they want (say, `example.com/offline/stuff-saying-what-they-want-here/`), and the server generates a page with that data embedded in it along with a manifest for the page and any assets it requires. So at that point, that information is available offline on that URL. When it loads, the page registers itself in a list in `localStorage`, giving a description of the page and its URL.

The list page (say, `example.com/offline/list/`) has its own manifest and assets, which don't change often because it's driven entirely by that `localStorage` information. It shows the list of things they have offline with links to them. It's primarily a convenience for users, in case they forget to bookmark the individual things they take offline; e.g., the idea is that they'll bookmark the list once, and never have to worry about bookmarking individual pages. (They could go hunting through their history, but it's a pain.) The list page keeps itself up-to-date by getting the list of known pages from `localStorage` when it loads, and subscribing to the `storage` event so if you load other pages in other tabs while the list is open, it sees them arrive and updates its list.

So without knowing anything about your app, it sounds like perhaps your main page could be like or list page, and clicking "sync" could open a page for the PDF, generating the manifest on the fly, and that page could register the PDF in `localStorage` the way we do with our offline pages so the main page can show their status correctly.

Obviously, there's potential there for the actual appcache and our `localStorage` list to get out of sync; we can't help it if a user clears appcache (which would make us list things that can't really be viewed offline) or clears `localStorage` (which would make is not list things they could view offline), but there we are. Users mostly don't do that, all that often.

In the future, you'll get ***much*** more granularity and control with [service workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/), but for now since [service worker support is very thin on the ground so far](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers), we're stuck with appcache and its fairly stodgy way of defining offline assets.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My pdfs are dynamic and user specific. I wouldn't know in prior about the pdfs that a user is associated with.

Comment: @user1455719: That's not necessarily a problem, it just means that you have to generate a manifest in response to a specific request. We do that in an app I work on where users can take a list of appointments offline; the URL contains the search information, and the page (with the appointment data in it) and manifest are generated accordingly.

Comment: My application is basically an angularjs application. When the application is loaded in the browser then i store the details of the associated pages into the browser via a manifest file. And when the user clicks on a 'SYNC' button then I communicate with the server and fetches all the pdfs associated with the user. If I have to persist these pdfs using the manifest then how can I do it ?.....the manifest is already stored

Comment: @user1455719: I've updated the answer for how we handle something similar. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

T.J. Crowder is right: if your PDFs are static and known in advance, then [AppCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) is the way to go. Unfortunately it does mean that each and every PDF will be saved in the user's browser when they first load the site, but maybe that's what you want.

Else if the PDFs are dynamic and not known in advance, then yeah, you may see performance problems from PouchDB with 5MB attachments. But if you want to try it out, then check out [PouchDB attachments](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html) and [blob-util](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util). `blobUtil.createObjectURL()` is exactly what you're looking for in terms of a "local URL."

Comment: Thanks nlawson, just wondering if its possible to store these pdfs to the browsers sandbox filesystem using fileApi. Or if I go with the pouch db attachments then do we have any limit (is there a way I can find out how much space is left in the browser db for further storage)

Comment: *"Unfortunately it does mean that each and every PDF will be saved in the user's browser when they first load the site..."* No it doesn't. It means that PDFs specific to a given request with a specific URL are loaded. So one makes sure the request contains the relevant information in order to return the correct PDFs.

Comment: Ah sure, I was thinking of a single-page environment. In a multi-page environment you could definitely have different AppCache manifests. :)

Comment: user1455719: As for "browsers sandbox filesystem," the FileSystem API is only in Chrome and deprecated: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Comment: my application is an angularjs application. i use the manfest to store the associated pages into the browser when the page is initialliy loaded.Is it possible to update an already stored maniifest with a new one